# RTSP GStreamer Server for windows

Tags: windows, gstreamer, rtsp

I want to create a basic GStreamer server for some test. Indeed I want to create a RTSP MediaPlayer which reads an IPCAM videostream in RTSP. So for my tests, I want to create a RTSP GStreamer server on windows. I found some tutos but only for Linux. Would you have any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the GStreamer RTSP server, but another alternative would be to use the cross-platform RTSP server implementation from www.live555.com.

Comment: Hey that's funny, someone told me about this exactly yesterday, but not for the same purposes !
Thanks I'm gonna see this ;)

Comment: Finally I did easier. I used VLC to stram my video. If I can indeed connect with another VLC, now it remains to do with a virtual device. Not done yet, but doing it !